# How to change the font in Markdown cells when they are in Edit Mode?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to change the font type in Markdown cells when I am editing them. 
How Can I do that?

I can edit the file `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` and change the font when they are "run":

```
div.text_cell_render {
    font-family: 'Linux Libertine O';
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

As shown in the figure, the upper half is a Markdown cell in edit mode, and that is the place where I want to change the font.
[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

A simple possibility is

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display
display(HTML('<style>.CodeMirror{font-family:whatever}</style>')
```

but beware that the code above changes also the fonts used for

1. editing cells of code
2. rendered code cells

Also note, that my simple proposal works on a notebook by notebook base, you have to add the lines to every notebook you want to modify. On the contrary, if you have a `custom.css` file where it can be accessed by `jupiter` during startup you can add the `font-family:whatever` to it, to make the customization hold for every notebook that you are using.

For an example of permanent customization please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504551/different-fonts-when-editing-code-and-markdown-cells-in-the-jupyter-notebook) from [Joel Ostblom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166823/joel-ostblom) — in a nutshell, edit `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` and put in it

```
.CodeMirror pre {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 14pt;
    ...
}
```

Comment: this only changes the font of code cells, not rendered markdown cells for me

Comment: Exactly so. That's OK as the question was not about the fonts used by Markdown to render the markdown cells, but the font used by CodeMirror to edit them.

Comment: @gboffi Do you know if it is possible to change the markdown edit font without affecting code cells? I asked this related question separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504551/different-fonts-when-editing-code-and-markdown-cells-in-the-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @JoelOstblom I don't know now but I'll have a look at it.