# Different font settings for editing code and markdown cells in the Jupyter Notebook

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In the Jupyter notebook, I would like to use the regular Ubuntu font when *editing* markdown cells and UbuntuMono for code cells. I can change the fonts of both these cell types simultaneously by editing `.jupyter/custom/custom.css` like so:

```
.CodeMirror pre {
    font-family: "Ubuntu Mono", monospace;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

I can also change the formatting of the headers in the markdown code cells:

```
.cm-header {
    font-size: 110%;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
}
```

As well as how the text looks when rendered (after executing a markdown cell):

```
div.text_cell_render {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

However, I don't understand which css classes I could use to discriminate between code cells and paragragh/body text in markdown cells in edit mode. I tried the object inspector in Firefox, but the input text for both cell types show up with the same span tags and css classes. I have tried many of [the combinations listed here](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes/blob/master/jupyterthemes/layout/cells.less#L317-L411), but it seems like I just can't find the right one, any ideas?

Comment: I am a Javascript ignorant, so this idea could not be a sensible one, however:  CodeMirror knows the difference, is it possible that you have to customize CodeMirror rather than Jupyter?

Comment: @gboffi Unfortunately, I am also Javascript ignorant... How do you know that CodeMirror can tell the difference, because they are executed differently? I also asked this on the [Jupyter Notebook issue list](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2889), but no replies yet.

Comment: @gboffi Just received a reply over at GitHub. I posted the solution below, works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received a reply from the Jupyter Notebook issue linked in the comments of my questions here. It is possible to combine CSS selector, so the following solves my problem:

```
.text_cell .CodeMirror pre {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```