# Changing Jupyter markdown render font

Tags: pycharm, jupyter-notebook

As I am currently trying to set up PyCharm to work with Jupyter Notebooks I encountered a problem with the way a markdown cell is being rendered.
[image]

In the picture [PyCharm Fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjagO.jpg) you can see, that the font for my code cell is "Consolas". But the font for a markdown cell is not being rendered in Consolas but what looks like "Time New Roman".
Is there a way to change the font a markdown cell is displayed in PyCharm.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/37895824/598513 they refer to `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`. My PyCharm does render all markdown into an empty line so cannot test this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font using html? Markdown will usually let you manipulate something using HTML if it cannot do it.

Try something like this:

Sample text formatted with inline CSS.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_family_(HTML)